# Basic JQuery Slider Prev and Next Button Bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I using [Basic JQuery Slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/) to build slider, but somehow the prev and next button cannot work. Can anyone tell me why?

This is the website: http://compramais.nuvemshop.com.br/

Comment: Add some code instead of just a link so we have something to work with.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

jquery call by first of other scripts, use JQuery before others Scripts

example error:

```
<script src="js/action.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

example sucess:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/action.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: this is because some par of first js are used in second js